# How to fix this getStaticPaths error in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

i am getting this Error: A required parameter (post.Id) was not provided as a string in getStaticPaths for /posts/[post.Id]

Even if I manually provide the path as '1' '2' or '3'
sometimes it gives me error to res.json() stating that res.json() is not a function

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

function Post({ post }) {
  const router = useRouter();

  if (router.isFallback) {
    return <div>getting Data...</div>;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h2>
        {post.id} {post.title}
      </h2>
      <p>{post.body}</p>
    </>
  );
}

export default Post;

export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  const { params } = context;
  const response = await fetch(
    `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${params.postId}`
  );
  const data = await response.json();

  if (!data.id) {
    return {
      notFound: true, //showing 404 page
    };
  }

  console.log(`Generating page for /posts/${params.postId}`);
  return {
    props: {
      post: data,
    },
  };
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const response = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
  const data = await response.json();
  const paths = data.map((post) => {
    return {
      params: { postId: `${post.id}` },
    };
  });

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: true,
  };
}
```

this will be generated dynamically

Comment: have you tried with `toString()`, `params: { postId: post.id.toString() }`

Comment: yeah I have used this before but it gives me the same error

Comment: can you update the component code in the question?

Comment: 'post.Id' !== 'postId'

Comment: this is whole file @AselaPriyadarshana

Comment: Is the file named `[postId].js`?

Comment: You have to change your dynamic page name to `[postId]` to match the `postId` parameter passed in the `paths` array inside `getStaticPaths`. The dynamic page name matters and must match the parameter you use in code.

Comment: This is the basic Next concept  that the file name should same as the passing parameter @juliomalves so that's not the problem here

Comment: yes its [postId].js @don_aman

Comment: Your error message indicates otherwise: `Error: A required parameter (post.Id) was not provided as a string in getStaticPaths for /posts/[post.Id]`. This shows that your page is called `/posts/[post.Id]` (and not `/posts/[postId]` as you claim)  and expects the param to be `post.Id`, which again doesn't match your code.

Comment: run the same project on a different machine and works just fine sometimes I don't understand error behaviors.